# How can I make an alias that has an executable's name

Tags: bash, alias

I tried to implement the following line in my `.bashrc`,

```bsh
alias ./my_exec='printf "foo"'
```

However, the alias doesn't work, and the following line appears :

```
bash: alias: `./my_exec': invalid alias name
```

I know that the `zsh` terminal can make this work, but I wouldn't switch to it for this only thing.

Is there is a way I can make this alias work ?

Comment: You need to use a valid name, such as: `alias my_exec='printf "foo"'`.  Or, is there some reason that you want the `./` as part of the alias name?

Comment: Yes, the `./` is necessary to me

Comment: And, the **reason** for that is?  If you want people here to provide useful help, it would help if you explained **why** you want to do this.

Comment: Prank a friend, so that his ./my_exec outputs "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)"
I have `zsh`, so he could prank me by doing it, I just want payback

Comment: @HeyShafty "*Prank a friend*".  You need to think of better excuses when asking questions on SE.

Comment: If the goal is a prank, why not alias `ls` or some other command that he is sure to use (and doesn't require `./` in the name)?

Comment: I'm sorry, be every reason is valid for everyone to learn new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need a function

```
my_exec(){
   print "foo"
}
```

this found for me,

```
countryip(){

  COUNTY="$(whois $1 | grep ountry))"
  echo "$COUNTRY $1 \n"

}

$ countryip 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Wow it worked actually
```
./my_exec() {
    printf "foo\n"
}
```

Comment: @HeyShafty also `../foo/bar(){ echo yeah; }; ../foo/bar` I think you should make your own answer with that -- notice however that it only works in `bash` and `zsh`.

Answer (score 15):

#### In bash-4.x

```
$ BASH_ALIASES[./my_exec]='echo yes'
$ ./my_exec
yes
```

According to the bash [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SuSE+Linux%2Fi386+11.3&arch=default&format=html#end), you cannot use `/` in an alias name:

> The characters **`/`**, `$`, `` ` ``, and `=` and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting  characters listed above may not appear in an alias name.

When defining an alias via the `alias name=val` syntax, bash will refuse any alias name that contains any character defined by the regex:

```
[ \t\n&();<>|\\"'`$/]
```

See the [`legal_alias_name()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c#n397) function in its source code. Notice that the lack of `=` above is not an omission; the impossibility of using it in an alias name is simply an artifact of the syntax.

But you **can** use some of those characters in an alias, by defining it indirectly via the `BASH_ALIASES` array:

```
$ BASH_ALIASES['/a=$']='echo yes'; /a=$
yes
```

This was **"[fixed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?id=36f2c406ff27995392a9247dfa90672fdaf7dc43#n188)" in bash-5.0** and you're no longer able to use `/` in alias names. But, for consolation, you can still use `=`:

```
bash-5.0-18-g36f2c406$ BASH_ALIASES[ef=g]='echo yess'
bash-5.0-18-g36f2c406$ ef=g
yess
bash-5.0-18-g36f2c406$ echo $ef
<nothing>
```

#### Alias names in the susv4 [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_10)

> 3.10 Alias Name

> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores,
> digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set and any of the
> following characters: `!`, `%`, `,`, `@`.

> Implementations may allow other characters within alias names as an extension.

So both `bash` and `zsh` (which allows `/` to be used in alias names directly) are within the standard.

#### Slashes and other funny chars in function names

In `bash` and `zsh`, a `/` can be used directly in a function name:

```
$ /bin/sh(){ echo no /bin/sh today; }
$ /bin/sh -c ls
no /bin/sh today
```

This is a non portable extension; a standard shell is only required to support [function names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) which contain [ascii letters, digits and underscores, and don't start with a digit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235).

In `bash`, a function name can be made up of any characters except `$`, with the condition that is doesn't contain only digits and within the constraints imposed by the function definition syntax. You can look at [`execute_intern_function()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5823) and [`check_identifier()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c#n346) for all the details.

In `zsh` the all-digits constraint doesn't apply, and a function name can also be quoted/escaped in the definition:

```
zsh$ 666() echo "$0"; \$() echo "$0"
zsh$ 666; $
666
$
```