# How to start and disown a process in a single line?

Tags: bash, process, disown

I noticed that many times I need to start a process and disown it immediately. I trying to achieve this **in a single line**. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: `sleep 600 & disown`. If it's something else you're after, add more details to your Q.

Comment: @mosvy The above thing works for me, but now I am trying to find a way to shorten the command further. What I am looking for is to write a command and then give one or two keystrokes to achieve the disowning action. Like typing "sleep 600 dn" and pressing Enter would start the sleep 600 and disown it, and similarly "nautilus dn" would start nautilus and disown it.

Comment: `alias -- -=disown` will let you write things like `sleep 600 &-`, but I don't think that's really worth it.

Comment: I am trying to get the ampersand included in the alias, but the interpreter then treats the alias as an argument to the process. Trying to find a way to avoid that.

Comment: @mosvy I have seen the usage of alias command with '=' but not with with "--" as you have mentioned in the comment. Can you tell about it or mention a source of info about it? Thanks

Comment: what source do you need? If you don't use the `--`, bash will complain that `-=` is an invalid option ;-)

Comment: more info about tricky characters in aliases in my own answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512194/308316), which contains some reference to the bash manpage and standards.

Comment: ok, in case you didn't know that, using a `--` is the standard convention used by unix command to separate switches/options from other arguments, see [getopt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html). bash's `alias` builtin is following that convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me as desired:

```
intended_process & disown $!
```

It seems that the $! part is optional

Thanks for the suggestion @mosvy