# Can I avoid using eval in alias re-definition?

Tags: shell, scripting, alias, eval

My system: Linux Mint 19.3.

My default shell: Bash.

---

Problem: I *do not like* using `eval` ([man page](https://ss64.com/bash/eval.html)) if unnecessary.

---

Question: Is there another way of redefining stored alias, which I currently do as follows:

```sh
# remove the alias for now
unalias "$some_alias_name"
...
# re-define that alias
eval "$some_alias_contents"
```

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what your problem is, but maybe look into using the [`BASH_ALIASES` array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512194/308316).

Comment: And there's nothing wrong with `eval`: bash calls `eval` for each line from the script, anyways.